# Converge properties of Taylor Series expansion of complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion, absolute-convergence

I need to find the convergence properties of the Taylor Expansion of

$$f(z)=\frac{z}{z-1}$$

---

I found the Taylor Series:

$$\sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{j+1}(z-i)^{j-1}}{(i-1)^j}$$

Then I used the "ratio test" to find out when it converges:

$$\lim_{j\to\infty}\left| \frac{\frac{(-1)^{j+2}(z-i)^{j}}{(i-1)^{j+1}}}{\frac{(-1)^{j+1}(z-i)^{j-1}}{(i-1)^j}} \right| = \left| \frac{(-1)(z-i)}{(i-1)} \right| < 1$$

So the series converges when $|z|<1$.

[However wolfalpha disagrees.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/widget/widgetPopup.jsp?p=v&id=f9476968629e1163bd4a3ba839d60925&title=Taylor%20Series&theme=blue&i0=z%2F%28z-1%29&i1=z&i2=i&i3=3&podSelect=&showAssumptions=1&showWarnings=1)

And I cannot spot my error?!

EDIT:

Forgot to mention: Expanding at $z=i$ and fixed typo.

EDIT: Wolframalpha says the expansion converges when $\sqrt{2}|z-i|<2$.

Comment: Should converge for $|z|<1$ not $z>1$.  Is that the confusion, or just a typo?

Comment: Wait, are you expanding at $z=0$ or around $z=i$?

Comment: Cuz that's not the expansion for $z=0$.

Comment: @GregoryGrant yes at z=i Sorry forgot to mention.

Comment: Ah I see.  It must converge then for a disk around $z=i$, so not $|z|<1$ which is a disk around $0$.  Should be more like $|z-i|<R$ for some $R$.  Probably $R=i$ but I didn't work it out.

Comment: What does woflram say is the answer?

Comment: @GregoryGrant The answer given is $\sqrt{2}|z-i|<2$. You're right that the disk must be centred at $z=i$. I forgot about that. The theory says that the convergence occurs over the largest open disk centered at $i$ over which $f(z)$ is analytic.

Comment: So you need to know for which $z$ is $\left|\frac{z-i}{i-1}\right|$ is less than one.  That is assuming you have the formula right.

Comment: And $|i-1|=\sqrt{2}$ so that's where that's probably coming from.

Comment: Yes exactly because then $|z-i|<\sqrt{2}$.  So you've done this right.

Comment: @GregoryGrant According to the theory, you can simply look at $f(z)$, figure out that it is not analytic at $z=1$ and then just get the answer immediately: $|z-i|<\sqrt{2}$. So I never needed to find the converge of the series by the ratio test?!

Comment: Yes you are absolutely correct.  The OP however asked where the mistake was in his argument, not for the absolutely most elegant method to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have done this right.  You need to find the $z$ for which $\left|\frac{z-i}{i-1}\right|<1$.  Now $|i-1|=\sqrt{2}$ so this is the same as

$|z-i|<\sqrt{2}$.

Since $\sqrt{2}=2/\sqrt{2}$ this is the same as woflram's answer.

Comment: OK that clears things up! Thanks